# JSON.stringify bug in firefox

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

I'm developing a web analytics for my app.

Client side, I send to the server the `window.location` object over a `JSON.stringify(window.location)`.

The object is properly stringified in chrome, IE, opera... but in Firefox, it just return `{"constructor":{}}`.

What's happen with Firefox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it doesn't work under FireFox (I assume it has something to do with the fact that properties of `window.location` are actually getters/setters in FireFox), but here's a simple solution: just copy the object.

```
var copy = {};
for (var i in window.location) {
    copy[i] = window.location[i];
}
JSON.stringify(copy);
```

Comment: It has to do with the properties not being own properties of the object but rather properties on the prototype, which is what the spec requires...

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, can't you simply create a new object that isn't the [`Location` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), but just a simple KVP object?

```
JSON.stringify({
    href:     window.location.href,
    protocol: window.location.protocol,
    host:     window.location.host,
    hostname: window.location.hostname,
    port:     window.location.port,
    pathname: window.location.pathname,
    search:   window.location.search,
    hash:     window.location.hash,
    username: window.location.username,
    password: window.location.password,
    origin:   window.location.origin
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) is an instance of [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) interface. You probably want to get its url as string. Try [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.href) instead.

Comment: @freakish, I'm pretty sure OP wants to send URL of a current page.

Comment: Where does OP state that? There's even more: he clearly states that "The object is properly stringified in chrome", so he actually want the object jsonified.

Comment: You can also jsonify a string. And href contains all the information from the object. It is not conveniently parsed though.

Answer (score 0):

Freakish solution does work.

```
var window_location = {};
for (var i in window.location) {
    window_location[i] = window.location[i];
}
alert(JSON.stringify(window_location));
```

See this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolino/75sVT/)...